# Exclude specific url in htaccess with dynamic following content

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

i do have the following .htaccess from a wordpress installation

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I now want to exlude a specific path (which should not be handled by wordpress). This works with the following

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo$ [NC] #<-----------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

how can i exclude every path beginning with 'foo' like 'foo/bar' or 'foo/bar/foo2/bar2'?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found my mistake. I will leave this for anybody who might have the same 'problem'. I have inside the 'foo' folder another .htaccess for handling the incoming requests. And this .htaccess had a wrong RewriteBase. 
It was

```
RewriteBase /
```

and needed to be

```
RewriteBase /foo/
```